# Redirect on correct pagination index page after edit

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to edit(edit.cto) on page 2 but after edit it's always redirecting to the index page 1.
How can i redirect on right pagination?

expected-> 
https://localhost/erp-development/EmployeeMonthlySalaries/index/page:2

getting -> https://localhost/erp-development/EmployeeMonthlySalaries/index/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using session.

For example in index controller set:

```
$this->request->session()->write('referer', ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); //cakephp 3

$this->Session->write('referer', ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); //cakephp 2
```

Then in edit controller:

```
return $this->redirect($this->request->session()->read('referer')); //cakephp 3

return $this->redirect($this->Session->read('referer')); //cakephp 2
```

Comment: Thanks. But here it's redirecting to https://localhost/erp-development/erp-development/EmployeeMonthlySalaries/index/page:2       project name is coming twice

Comment: Try with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` instead of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Do not access superglobals directly when you're using CakePHP! This will only get you in trouble, especially in the testing environment. Use the abstracted methods provided by the request object instead!

Comment: I would never use session, this is usually a big antipattern and usability killer here. Instead pass query strings with the referrer you want to go back to. This also works properly with multiple tabs open of the same website, and even if the session is lost/renewed after timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would recommend not to use named parameters, as they are a CakePHP-only feature and not standard.
I would recommend to use regular GET parameters using:

```
'Paginator' => array(
    'limit' => 15,
    'paramType' => 'querystring'
),
```

in your components definition.

I would then build all URLs using a custom-defined makeUrl() function, or overriding HtmlHelper::link() one, so that they all contain the querystring received.
Your edit action will then have the URL: /controller/edit/?page=2
and you edit action will know how to build the redirect URL /controller/index?page=2

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace below redirect code where you write your redirect code in controller:

```
<?php $this->redirect($this->referer()); ?>
```